# Binding a list of objects to a table with static rows and dynamic column values

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I'm creating a table with editable cells in an asp.net mvc application, binding with Knockoutjs

Given this c# viewmodel

```
[Serializable]
public class Step4 {
    public IList<Projection> Projections { get; set; }
}

public class Projection : IYear {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Turnover { get; set; }
    public string DirectCostOfOperation { get; set; }
}
```

and table

```
                <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered" style="background-image: none;">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="bg-blueberry white" style="background-image: none;">
                        <th class="text-center" style="width: 250px">Years</th>
                        <th class="text-center">@Model.Step4.Projections[0].Id</th>
                        <th class="text-center">@Model.Step4.Projections[1].Id</th>
                        <th class="text-center">@Model.Step4.Projections[2].Id</th>
                        <th class="text-center">@Model.Step4.Projections[3].Id</th>
                        <th class="text-center">@Model.Step4.Projections[4].Id</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="bg-carbon white" colspan="6">PROFIT AND LOSS ACCOUNT</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="italic font-normal">Turnover</th>
                        <td><input data-bind="value: Model.Step4.Projections[0].Turnover" /></td>
                        <td><input data-bind="value: Model.Step4.Projections[1].Turnover" /></td>
                        <td><input data-bind="value: Model.Step4.Projections[2].Turnover" /></td>
                        <td><input data-bind="value: Model.Step4.Projections[3].Turnover" /></td>
                        <td><input data-bind="value: Model.Step4.Projections[4].Turnover" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="italic font-normal">Direct Cost of Operations</th>
                        <td><input data-bind="value: Model.Step4.Projections[0].DirectCostOfOperation" /></td>
                        <td><input data-bind="value: Model.Step4.Projections[1].DirectCostOfOperation" /></td>
                        <td><input data-bind="value: Model.Step4.Projections[2].DirectCostOfOperation" /></td>
                        <td><input data-bind="value: Model.Step4.Projections[3].DirectCostOfOperation" /></td>
                        <td><input data-bind="value: Model.Step4.Projections[4].DirectCostOfOperation" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-right bg-lightcarbon white">Gross Profit</th>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

As you can see the first column contains the row's title and then the values for each year.

currently, I'm trying to bind the individual items to the editable cells, which is resulting is this error:

**SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'Turnover' of undefined or null reference**

From researching, it is suggested that using a Foreach to repeat the columns will be a better approach in resolving this issue.

Please, can someone tell or show me how I can repeat the columns in the static rows?

**Solution:**
Using Denis idea, I updated my table to this:

```
 <tr>
   <th class="italic font-normal">Turnover</th>
   <!-- ko foreach: Model.Step4.Projections -->
    <td><input data-bind="value: Turnover, uniqueName: true" /></td>
   <!-- /ko -->
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <th class="italic font-normal">Direct Cost of Operations</th>
   <!-- ko foreach: Model.Step4.Projections -->
    <td><input data-bind="value: DirectCostOfOperation, uniqueName: true" /></td>
   <!-- /ko -->
 </tr>
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Controller:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var p1 = new Projection() { Id = 1, DirectCostOfOperation = "111", Turnover = "100" };
        var p2 = new Projection() { Id = 2, DirectCostOfOperation = "222", Turnover = "200" };
        var p3 = new Projection() { Id = 3, DirectCostOfOperation = "333", Turnover = "300" };
        var p4 = new Projection() { Id = 4, DirectCostOfOperation = "444", Turnover = "400" };
        var p5 = new Projection() { Id = 5, DirectCostOfOperation = "555", Turnover = "500" };

        Step4 step = new Step4();
        step.Projections = new List<Projection> { p1, p2, p3, p4, p5 };

        return View(step);
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class Step4
{
    public IList<Projection> Projections { get; set; }
}

public class Projection : IYear
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Turnover { get; set; }
    public string DirectCostOfOperation { get; set; }
}

public interface IYear
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Turnover { get; set; }
    string DirectCostOfOperation { get; set; }
}
```

**View:**

```
@model Example.Controllers.Step4

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered" style="background-image: none;">
    <thead>
        <tr class="bg-blueberry white" style="background-image: none;">
            <th class="text-center" style="width: 250px">Years</th>
            @foreach (var projection in Model.Projections)
            {
                <th class="text-center">@projection.Id</th>
            }
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th class="bg-carbon white" colspan="6">PROFIT AND LOSS ACCOUNT</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="italic font-normal">Turnover</th>
            @foreach (var projection in Model.Projections)
            {
                <th class="text-center">@projection.Turnover</th>
            }
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="italic font-normal">Direct Cost of Operations</th>
            @foreach (var projection in Model.Projections)
            {
                <th class="text-center">@projection.DirectCostOfOperation</th>
            }
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-right bg-lightcarbon white">Gross Profit</th>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Output:**

[image]